# Legendre transformation / Legendre-Fenchel transformation as a function on the dual space

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I'm trying to get a better understanding of what the essence of the Legendre transformation resp. the Legendre-Fenchel transformation is. In particular, it is unclear to me why the Legendre-Fenchel transformation $f^{\star}$ of a function $f \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is necessarily a function on the dual space $\mathbb{R}^{n \, \star}$ and what the deeper significance of this is.

1. Let's consider the *Legendre transform* first. Let $f:D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable and convex function. Then the Legendre transform is given by

$f^{\star}(u) = \langle  u,x(u) \rangle - f \big( x(u) \big) \quad \text{ with } \quad x(u)=(Df)^{-1}(u) \quad \text{ and } \quad u \in D^{\star}=Df(D)  $.

So $u=f'(x) = \nabla f(x) $ is a linear function $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and thus a linear form. We can consider it to be $u \in \mathbb{R}^{n \, \star}$, and $f^{\star}$ is a function on the dual space, given my argument is correct.

2. Now in the more general case, the *Legendre-Fenchel transformation* or *convex conjugate* of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is not necessarily differentiable or convex is given by

$f^{\star}(u) = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \left\{ \langle  u,x(u) \rangle - f \big( x(u) \big) \right\} \quad \text{with} \quad u \in D^{\star} = \left\{ u \in \mathbb{R}^n : \; \sup_{x \in D} (\langle u,x \rangle - f(x)) < \infty \right\}.$

Why can we say in this case that $ D^{\star} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n \, \star} $?

3. And in the even more general case where $f \in X$ with a real topological vector space X, why is $f^{\star}$ necessarily $ \in X^{\star}$?
4. What is the deeper significance of $f^{\star}$ being a function on the dual space? Why does it make the Legendre transformation so interesting? I'm particularly interested in this for understanding the relationship between Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formalism in physics.

Comment: The argument $u$ of $f^\star$ is paired with an argument $x$ of $f$. Hence, if the arguments of $f$ live in $X$, the arguments of $f^\star$ have to live in a space $X^\star$ which allows for the construct $\langle u, x \rangle$ for $u \in X^\star$, $x \in X$. In most (all?) cases, one uses the topological dual space $X^\star$.

Comment: @gerw, I understand that in case 3. we define u to be $ \in X^{\star}$. In case 1 I have shown that from the usual definition, e.g. Arnold, "Mathematical Methods in Classical Mechanics", this can be derived, too. But frequently I encounter the definition given for the case 2, e.g. Touchette, "Legendre-Fenchel Transform in a Nutshell", and in this case it is not clear to me why this definition is equivalent to u being $ \in \mathbb{R}^{n \, \star} $, in neither direction.

Comment: I'm also interested in these but I don't want to spend time trying to figure out what $D$ is in definition 1. Is it a ball, then what is $Df(D)$? if $Df$ is the differential from an $n$ dimension space to $\mathbb{R}$ the your $(Df)^{-1}(u)$ is an $n-1$ affine space, I really don't understand.\\ The first time I saw a good reason to distinguish a vector space and its dual was when one considers change of basis (action of $GL$), but this is not an intrinsic reason. I would now rather say that one could associate to a (non trivial) linear form its kernel which is a hyperplane...

Comment: while one would associate a line to a (non-trivial) vector. Also, an endomorphism on a finite dimension $E$, is a sum of rank one maps (elementary matrices) which are of the form $\lambda \otimes \mathbf{v}$ where $\lambda$ is a form ("line vector") while $\mathbf{v}$ is a ("column") vector. One usually identify line and column vectors but this implicitly uses the data of an inner product $\Leftrightarrow$ an isomorphism between the vector space $E$ and its dual $E^*$. Without this information, we really need both notions